# contact form receiving empty mail from website

Tags: javascript, php, html

i bought me a template for my website where also a finished cotact form was with it .

the think is that there is just a javascript text code so no php script . i wrote a php text by my self, and it is working but the thing is that if i click on send on my website , i will receive an email but it is empty . so name , email adress etc. is not transmitting.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

errors = new Array();
form = $('#contact');

form.submit(function() {
    $('#loading').fadeIn();
    $('#error, #success').hide();
    if(validate()) { 
        submission();
        return false;
    } else {
        $('#loading').hide();
        $('#error, #results').fadeIn();
        return false;
    };
})

function validate() {
    errors.length=0;

    $('.req').each(function() {
        val = $(this).val();
        id = $(this).attr('id');
        if(!val) {
            errors.push(id);
        }
    })

    if(errors.length === 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        $.each(errors, function(index, value) {
            $('#' + value).addClass('error');
        });
        return false;
    }
}

function submission() {
    var name = $("input#name").val();  
    var email = $("input#email").val();  
    var phone = $("input#phone").val();
    var comments = $("#comments").val();
    var dataString = 'name='+ name + '&email=' + email + '&phone=' + phone + '&comments=' + comments;  
    //alert (dataString);return false;  
    $.ajax({  
      type: "POST",  
      url: "senden.php",  
      data: dataString,  
      success: function() {  
        $('#results, #success').fadeIn();
        $('#loading').hide();
      }  
    });  
    return false;
}

})
```

thats the script i put all the script and php part icluding the html form into a jsfiddle file. i hope ya could help me. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ck4Z7/)

Comment: It's easier to build the data as an object: `data: $('form').serialize()`

Comment: $nachricht is not populated with the form data

Comment: im not so into javascript. so i think that this would make more problems if im trying this. 

normaly should be the script okay, i mean i think there is something wrong with the php script. cause if you click on send im receiving an email but it is empty

Comment: And your PHP itself is 100% Kosher?

Comment: no i never said that it is kosher :). i tryed it by my self and thats how far i get . what should i change in my php script to receive the things like name data ,

Comment: changed them to '$name=$$_POST['name'];' but i still get nothing transmitted

Comment: Sidenote: I noticed you don't have one for `phone` - I.e.: `$phone=$data['phone']; `

Comment: I made a mistake with `$name=$$_POST['name'];` I took out the extra `$` but soon noticed in your fiddle, that it would not have made a difference. I deleted that comment.

Comment: This `mail('it@awesom-media.de', 'E-Mail von der Webseite', $nachricht, 'From: ' . $mail);` should probably be `mail('it@awesom-media.de', 'E-Mail von der Webseite', $comments, 'From: ' . $mail);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you even look at the PHP script you posted? You are setting the variables `$name`, `$email`, and `$comments`, but then you are using `$nachricht` and `$email` (which do not exist) when you are sending the mail :\

```
$data=$_POST;
$name=$data['name'];
$email=$data['email'];  
$comments=$data['comments'];
```

Those variables are not used here:

```
mail('it@awesom-media.de', 'E-Mail von der Webseite', $nachricht, 'From: ' . $email);
```

Comment: now i have it like this

'<?php

$data=$_POST;
$name=$_POST['name'];
$email=$data['email'];  
$comments=$data['comments'];   

mail('it@awesom-media.de', 'E-Mail von der Webseite', $comments, 'From: ' . $email);
?>'

im getting the comment and the email but no name if i put $name into it, well i get the name field but in the mail is the name field written into the comment field

Comment: Use the string `"$name <$email>"` instead of `$name`. This will make the email header appear to come from `$name` but then when you reply it will go to `$email`. If you just want to display their email somewhere you can add it to the subject. Something like `'E-Mail von der Webseite from ' . $email` for the subject.